# getattribute value in android string

Tags: java, android, getattribute

i have to develop android xml parsing examples.

Here i have to get the attribute value...

This is code  for get the id:

```
private int id;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

here i get the arrtibute value for int:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Element e = (Element) nodeList.item(i);

            Employee employee = new Employee();

           employee.setId(Integer.parseInt(e.getAttribute(ATTR_ID)));
```

ok its done well..

now i have to get the arrtibute value for string...

```
private String name;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

How can i get it ???

pls give me code for these...

Comment: Where do you add String objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's a number of important pieces of information missing from your question, but assuming that the name field and getter/setter methods reside in the Employee object and that the name attribute exists on the same node as the id attribute, then the following code should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
{
    Element e = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setId(Integer.parseInt(e.getAttribute(ATTR_ID)));
    employee.setName(e.getAttribute(NAME)));
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for posting your answer.here i got the o/p after add these line: employee.setName(String.valueOf(e.getAttribute(NODE_NAME)));